# PTY allocation request failed on channel 0 - gentoo in openvz

Tags: linux, openvz, gentoo

I keep getting `PTY allocation request failed on channel 0` once I hit "some" limit, upon trying to connect with `ssh` or locally with `vzctl enter 10x`

I have multiple developers accessing same test server, sharing screens etc. Some system information:

Server: Gentoo OS
Virtualization: Open VZ

under /dev/

```
crw-rw-rw-  1 root tty  5,  2 Sep 17 14:11 ptmx
```

under /pts/

```
crw--w---- 1 web    tty  136, 0 Sep 17 11:58 0
crw--w---- 1 web    tty  136, 2 Sep 17 11:58 2
crw--w---- 1 web    tty  136, 3 Sep 17 11:58 3
crw--w---- 1 webdev tty  136, 4 Sep 17 14:12 4
crw--w---- 1 web    tty  136, 5 Sep 17 11:58 5
crw--w---- 1 webdev tty  136, 6 Sep 17 14:12 6
crw--w---- 1 webdev tty  136, 7 Sep 17 14:12 7
crw--w---- 1 root   tty  136, 8 Sep 17 14:12 8

www0 dev # cat /proc/version 
Linux version 2.6.27-openvz-kiprensky.1-r1 (root@bdsamf) (gcc version 4.3.4 (Gentoo 4.3.4 p1.1, pie-10.1.5) ) #1 SMP Sat May 15 07:36:39 EEST 2010
```

so it appears once I'm hitting 8 psuedo terminals, no more new are being created. I tried obviously googling this issue, but it did not clear the sky this time.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://wiki.openvz.org/Man/vzctl.8

`--numpty items[:items]`

Number of pseudo-terminals (PTY). Note that in OpenVZ each container can have not more than 255 PTYs. Setting the barrier and the limit to different values does not make practical sense.

seems it's sometimes enough to ask the question properly to find the solution.